# Problem with hibernate or suspend in ubnutu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, suspend, hibernate

I have two problems. First is that when I suspend my HP laptop on Ubuntu 22.04, sometimes it cannot wake from suspension, and shows some information like the image below
[image]

What can be the source of the problem?
Another symptom is if I let it completely suspend and then close the lid, it would wake up correctly, but if I close the lid before it suspends, this picture comes up.
My second question is how hard I have tried, I couldn't make my Ubuntu suspend or hibernate by closing the lid. The only thing it does is make the system go to airplane mode.